# How to install mysql package for Visual Studio 2013 python tool

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I am new to python. I installed the python tool on Visual Studio 2013. How do I install mysql package/module??? I need to write python code which will interact with mysql DB.

Comment: any suggestion for python3.8??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the windows installer for MySQL-python:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5

Once installed properly, you should be able to run `import MySQLdb`

Comment: Note that there is no package "for" Visual Studio per se -- presumably you are just using Visual Studio as your IDE.

Comment: I install python 3.4. When I try to install the windows installer it asks for python 2.7

Comment: The package may not be compatible with Python 3.x -- you can proceed by installing Python 2.7 on your computer.

Comment: Thank you it is working now. If I code python with this mysql library and python 2.7 will the code work on CENTOS linux???

Comment: Yes, should work on any platform (including CentOS Linux), as long as you have Python 2.7 and MySQL-python installed. So on CentOS you'll probably need to pip install mysql-python. (Note that MySQL-python should work for some earlier versions of Python too, but your mileage may vary...).